# trouble creating a pre-event indicator variable

Tags: r, datetime, tidyverse

i am trying to make a variable to indicate whether or not a given year is the year just before a certain event, but i am having some trouble.

this is what my initial data looks like.

```
> dat
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   country  year event
   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1 a        2000     0
 2 a        2001     0
 3 a        2002     1
 4 a        2003     1
 5 a        2004     1
 6 a        2005     1
 7 b        2000     0
 8 b        2001     0
 9 b        2002     0
10 b        2003     0
11 b        2004     1
12 b        2005     1
```

since the event starts in 2002 for country `a` and 2004 for country `b`, i would want a new variable `pre_event` to have a value of `1` in 2001 and 2003, but have a value of `0` in all other years.

so far i only seem to be able to do part of this successfully.

```
> dat %>%
+   group_by(country) %>%
+   arrange(country, year) %>%
+   mutate(pre_event = lead(event))
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   country [2]
   country  year event pre_event
   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 a        2000     0         0
 2 a        2001     0         1
 3 a        2002     1         1
 4 a        2003     1         1
 5 a        2004     1         1
 6 a        2005     1        NA
 7 b        2000     0         0
 8 b        2001     0         0
 9 b        2002     0         0
10 b        2003     0         1
11 b        2004     1         1
12 b        2005     1        NA
```

but i want my data to look like this. what should i do?

```
   country  year event pre_event
   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 a        2000     0         0
 2 a        2001     0         1
 3 a        2002     1         0
 4 a        2003     1         0
 5 a        2004     1         0
 6 a        2005     1         0
 7 b        2000     0         0
 8 b        2001     0         0
 9 b        2002     0         0
10 b        2003     0         1
11 b        2004     1         0
12 b        2005     1         0
```

edit:

adding real snapshot of data:

```
structure(list(country_name = c("Guinea-Bissau", "Guinea-Bissau", 
"Guinea-Bissau", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guinea-Bissau", 
"Guinea-Bissau", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guinea-Bissau", 
"Guinea-Bissau", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guinea-Bissau", 
"Guinea-Bissau", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guinea-Bissau", 
"Guinea-Bissau", "Gambia", "Gambia", "Gambia", "Gambia", "Gambia", 
"Gambia", "Gambia", "Gambia", "Gambia", "Gambia", "Gambia", "Gambia", 
"Gambia", "Gambia", "Gambia", "Gambia", "Gambia", "Gambia", "Gambia", 
"Mali", "Mali"), year = c(1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 
1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 
1998, 1999, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 
1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 1981, 
1982), internalconflict = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), gdpgrowth = c(0.21656057, 0.10471205, 
-0.042654045, 0.034653414, 0.036682621, -0.035384621, 0, 0.043062218, 
0.067278333, -0.012893987, -0.13933238, 0.06913998, -0.0011880503, 
0.0085358936, 0.019053213, 0.021861792, 0.031022603, -0.29643786, 
0.056630101, -0.12586033, -0.019122632, -0.1731651, 0.11095698, 
-0.039950069, 0.096228868, 0.011862385, -0.057444274, 0.0049751345, 
-0.011138618, -0.013032082, -0.007978335, -0.008393826, -0.032121219, 
-0.022602938, -0.0088469042, 0.017218538, 0.018114341, 0.034760576, 
-0.03759395, 0.023437429)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), groups = structure(list(
    country_name = c("Gambia", "Guinea-Bissau", "Mali"), .rows = structure(list(
        20:38, 1:19, 39:40), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: @Ben, thanks. this works with my sample data, but it doesn't work with my real data. perhaps this is because some of the countries go in and out of the event state over the period of observation.

Comment: How about this: `dat %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(pre_event = ifelse(lead(event, default = 0) == 1 & event == 0, 1, 0))`?

Comment: @ben, this one returns zero for all years unfortunately

Comment: This seems to work for your example data. Could you share sample data using `dput(head(dat, 20))` or something similar to test out?

Comment: @ben just added some example output

Comment: Thanks - this is helpful - I assume `internalconflict` is your "event"? If so, I tried out the code and it does have a 1 in 1997 for Guinea-Bissau before 1998-1999 event...is that correct?

Comment: Here is what I tried: `dat %>%
  group_by(country_name) %>%
  mutate(pre_event = ifelse(lead(internalconflict, default = 0) == 1 & internalconflict == 0, 1, 0))`

Comment: @ben this looks like it works! thanks a lot!!!